# What is the syntax for an automatic link in Servicestack Markdown?

Tags: servicestack, markdown

I am trying to use the markdown syntax as described at http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autolink to add an automatic link to my markdown view from a property on my model like so:

```
<@Model.ActivationUrl>
```

This is rendered as:

```
<a href="&#109;&#x61;&#105;&#x6c;&#116;&#x6f;&#x3a;&#x40;&#77;&#111;&#100;e&#108;&#x2e;&#x41;&#99;&#116;&#105;&#118;&#x61;&#x74;&#x69;&#x6f;n&#x55;r&#x6c;">&#64;&#x4d;&#x6f;&#100;&#x65;&#108;&#x2e;&#x41;&#x63;&#116;&#105;&#x76;&#97;&#116;&#x69;&#x6f;&#110;&#85;&#x72;&#x6c;</a>
```

Which comes down to:

```
<a href="mailto:@Model.ActivationUrl">@Model.ActivationUrl</a>
```

So the @Model.ActivationUrl property is not expanded but interpreted as a mailto link. How can I prevent this?